# dropdown пункт меню jquery?

Tags: jquery

Как сделать чтобы была возможность навести указатель и кликнуть по раскрывающемуся контенту submenu?

```js
$('a').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').hide();
  });
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  menu item
</a>
<div class="sub-menu">
  <a href="#">
   1-Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat amet tempora dolores in.
 </a>
</div>
<a href="#">
  menu item
</a>
<div class="sub-menu">
  <a href="#">
   2-pLorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat amet tempora dolores in.
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Hover`-ом не сможете добитсья эффекта dropdown.

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
  });
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.sub-menu').hide();
});
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  menu item
</a>
<div class="sub-menu">
  <a href="#">
   1-Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat amet tempora dolores in.
 </a>
</div>
<a href="#">
  menu item
</a>
<div class="sub-menu">
  <a href="#">
   2-pLorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat amet tempora dolores in.
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: а если без клика? по menu-item будет осуществляться переход